# Unity3D 8th Wall XR, Make Camera Resolution To HD / FHD

Tags: unity-game-engine, 8thwall-xr

With 8th Wall XR is it possible to make AR apps with camera resolution quality in HD or Full HD?

Answer (score 0):

The camera resolution rendered will vary depending on the device being used.

For ARCore devices, the resolution is 1920x1080.
 
 For ARKit devices, the resolution is 1280x720 for devices under iOS 11.3 and 1920x1080 for 11.3+.
For all other devices, the resolution is 640x480.

While there isn’t a way to change these resolutions at the moment, we are looking to provide a higher resolution for non-ARKit and non-ARCore phones in a future release.